# M.2 NVMe Adapter not working

Tags: usb, nvme

I have an EZCast S8000 Adapter for my old SSD, which is working fine on my Windows partition on my Lenovo 720-15ikb, but on the Ubuntu 19.10 partition it just shows up for a second and unmounts immedately.

How can I run the USB-Adapter on Ubuntu?

Comment: After some debugging I've posted a bug in the usb_modeswitch package (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-modeswitch/+bug/1878921). It seems the manufacturer is using the same product id than another product (a display projector) therefore after inserting it tried to connect as a display :/ The good news is the developers are super responsive and might provide an update soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manufacturer used wrong product id (re-used from another product) and it messes up the USB flip mode (USB devices can go through 2 modes). The [usb-modeswitch](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-modeswitch) package takes care of this in Ubuntu.
There is a temporary fix. Edit your `/etc/usb_modeswitch.conf` file and disable the switching mode:

```
DisableSwitching=1
```

Then when you insert the device it should work. It works fine for me, I could re-format the partitions and use the device. I'm using the USB-C port though. Not sure it matters.

Package maintainers are looking at a way to distinguish this device using other properties. I've open a bug there:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-modeswitch/+bug/1878921

Comment: Great, this works! How did you find that out? I searched a lot too, but got no clue, what to look for.

Comment: I did `tail -f /var/log/syslog` , pressed a few times ENTER to make some separation then inserted the drive. I saw something was off with the usb_modeswitch (have a look, the error actually tells to contact the developers). So I did. Have a look at the bug, they proposed a better patch (which will eventually come in a future update of the usb-modeswitch-data package)